# can Kendo UI for Angular work with AngularJS 1.6 project

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am working on a AngularJS 1.6.6, it's NOT the Angular2/Angular4, project. I am curious if I get a license for KendoUI, will it work smoothly with AngularJS classic?

Answer (score 0):

It will work. You can refer the section [Supported AngularJS Versions](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/installation/prerequisites#supported-angularjs-versions) in their documentation for more details.

If you want to verify these for yourself before purchasing the license, you can update one of their [demos](http://dojo.telerik.com/AJAbE) with the exact version of AngularJS you wish to use and try it out.

Comment: He can also try the free and Open Source version [Kendo UI Core](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-ui/open-source-core) before purchasing. Although to be honest, I'm not too fond of their AngularJS implementation. It's just a thin wrapper on top of their jQuery modules and it usually takes a lot of boilerplate code to do the most simple things.